# Push to stack only works once - React Native Navigation V2

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I'm working with React-Native-Navigation v2 for the first time, modeling a simple app that has 3 tabs at the bottom and a sidebar that has a button which will navigate to a fourth screen when pressed mimicking a 'logout'.  This fourth tab will then have a button that mimics a 'login' by returning to the first screen which is part of the bottomTabs stack.

The code I have works, but only once.  After I have logged out (pushing new screen to the stack) I can then log back in (popping that screen back off the stack).  However when I try to logout again I'm not able to do it.  The functionality to push to the stack seems to no longer work.

```
handleLogOutPress = () => {
Navigation.push('CenterStack', {
  component: {
    name: 'navigationApp.FourthTabScreen',
    passProps: {
      text: 'Logged Out'
    },
    options: {
      topBar: {
        visible: false
      }
    }
  }
})
Navigation.mergeOptions('CenterStack', {
  sideMenu: {
    left: {
      visible: false
    }
  }
})
}


function handleLoginPress(){
  Navigation.pop('CenterStack')
}
```

This is how my stack is set up initially:

```
  Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    sideMenu: {
      left: {
        component: {
          id: 'SideMenu',
          name: 'navigationApp.SideMenu'
        }
      },
      center: {
        stack: {
          id: 'CenterStack',
          children: [
            {
              bottomTabs: {
                children: [
                  {
                    component: {
                      id: 'FirstTab',
                      name: 'navigationApp.FirstTabScreen',
                      passProps: {
                        text: 'Home',
                        id: 'FirstTab'
                      },
                      options: {
                        bottomTab: {
                          icon: images[0],
                          text: 'Home',
                          iconColor: 'darkblue',
                          selectedIconColor: 'lightblue'
                        },
                        topBar: {
                          visible: false
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  },
                  {
                    component: {
                      id: 'SecondTab',
                      name: 'navigationApp.SecondTabScreen',
                      passProps: {
                        text: 'Search',
                        id: 'SecondTab'
                      },
                      options: {
                        bottomTab: {
                          icon: images[1],
                          text: 'Search',
                          iconColor: 'darkblue',
                          selectedIconColor: 'lightblue'
                        },
                        topBar: {
                          visible: false
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  },
                  {
                    component: {
                      id: 'ThirdTab',
                      name: 'navigationApp.ThirdTabScreen',
                      passProps: {
                        text: 'Share',
                        id: 'ThirdTab'
                      },
                      options: {
                        bottomTab: {
                          icon: images[2],
                          text: 'Share',
                          iconColor: 'darkblue',
                          selectedIconColor: 'lightblue'
                        },
                        topBar: {
                          visible: false
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ],
              }
            }
          ],
        },
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I may be completely misunderstanding how push/pop works, any help and guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking in using `popToRoot` rather than `Pop` resolves this